# Multiply value from textbox with combobox and display in label in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm pretty new to programming in WPF with xaml and C# and I've searched the forum for a similar problem, but I couldn't find any solution to my problem.

I've made a combobox of three items, each item has a text content. When one of these items are selected, I want to multiply the value in a textbox with a number and display the result in a label. Here is my code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int a = Int32.Parse(weight.Text);
        double b;

        if (this.wcf.SelectedItem==weighing)
        {
            b = a * 1.03;
            wll.Content = b.ToString();
        }
        else if (this.wcf.SelectedItem == uptodate)
        {
            b = a * 1.1;
            wll.Content = b.ToString();
        }
        else if (this.wcf.SelectedItem == lessupdated)
        {
            b = a * 1.2;
            wll.Content = b.ToString();
        }

    }
```

"weight" is the name of the textbox, "wcf" is the name of the combobox, "weighing", "uptodate" and "lessupdated" is name of the combobox items and "wll" is the name of the label. These are defined in xaml in the main window.

Comment: It doesn't makes sense to read something in constructor (user didn't entered/selected something yet). More likely you want to use some event (e.g. combobox's `SelectionChanged` or `TextChanged`) and do above logic (parse, check and set) in there. Or what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an event handler for your combobox.
Something like:

```
<Combobox x:Name="wcf" SelectionChanged="cb_SelectionChanged">[...]</Combobox>
```

In your code behind:

```
private void cb_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
...
}
```

The method `cb_SelectionChanged` will be called each time you click on an item.

Comment: If I want to use the b variable further in a new if statement, after the if statement I just showed, I get an error of use of unassigned local variable. Do I need to convert the b variable to an int and the assign it again?

Comment: If you don't assign any value to the variable b, you can't e.g. increment it. At the initialization of the variable you can give it a default value (e. g. `double b = 0`) to use it further.